# What is "p" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, printf-debugging

I'm sure it's a silly question to those who know, but I can't find an explanation of what it does or what it is.

```
CSV.open('data.csv', 'r') do |row|
  p row
end
```

What does "`p row`" do?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## `p()` is a Kernel method

It writes `obj.inspect` to the standard output.

Because Object mixes in the Kernel module, the `p()` method is available everywhere.

It's common, btw, to use it in *poetry mode*, meaning that the parens are dropped. The CSV snippet can be written like...

```
CSV.open 'data.csv', 'r' do |row|
  p row
end
```

It's documented [here with the rest of the Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) module.

Comment: The direct link into the docs for p - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-p

Answer (score 24):

`Kernel#p` is the little debugging brother of `Kernel#puts`: it more or less works exactly like it, but it converts its arguments using `#inspect` instead of `#to_s`.

The reason why it has such a cryptic name is so that you can quickly throw it into an expression and take it out again when debugging. (I guess it's a lot less useful now that Ruby is getting better and better "proper" debugging support.)

Some alternatives to `Kernel#p` are `Kernel#pp` (pretty print) from the `pp` standard library and `Kernel#y` (YAML) from the `yaml` standard library.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try it?

```
>> [1,2,3].each { |d| p d }
1
2
3
```

Comment: Actually it calls `#inspect` to its argument first, but close 
enough ;)

Comment: True. Removed my 'alias' comment since it's just plain wrong. Maybe more like 'wrapper'.

Answer (score 2):

The other option for documentation that you already have on your system is the `ri` command. At any time you can type: `ri p` or if `p` is defined in a lot of places (which it is) for central commands you can try `ri Kernel.p`. Other good bets are `Array.<whatever method>` or `String.<whatever method>`.

If you end up installing a bunch of gems this will slow down a lot but you can look up the fastri gem which speeds up the lookup process incredibly.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel#p is less well known than print and puts.

It is similar to puts in that it adds a newline, but rather than calling to_s, p calls inspect.

References

http://garethrees.co.uk/2013/05/04/p-vs-puts-vs-print-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference between p and puts, you must understand difference between to_s() and instance() methods.

to_s is used to get string representation of an object while [instance](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inspect) is a more developer friendly version of to_s which gives contents of the objects as well.

```
class Dog
        def initialize(name, breed)
            @name = name
            @breed = breed
        end
        def to_s
            puts  "#@name's breed is #@breed."
        end
end

terra=Dog.new("Terra","Husky")
puts terra #Terra's breed is Husky.
p terra    #<Dog:0x00007fbde0932a88 @name="Terra", @breed="Husky">
```