# How to delete double quotation mark from ruby array?

Tags: ruby

Based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926822/how-to-delete-quotation-marks-in-an-array-in-ruby)
I tried to delete "" in the array on ruby

However still not get what I want, if anyone knows, please advice me

```
a = gets
lines = []
aaa = []
b = []
bb =[]
while line = gets do
  lines << line.chomp.split(' ')
end


for k in 0..(lines.size - 1) do
    b << lines[k][1].to_i + 1
end

for i in 0..(lines.size - 1)do
    bb << lines[i][0] + ' ' + b[i].to_s
end

for l in 0..(lines.size - 1)do
    p bb[l]
end
```

Input

```
3
Tanaka 18
Sato 50
Suzuki 120
```

Output

```
[["Tanaka", "18"], ["Sato", "50"], ["Suzuki", "120"]]
"Tanaka 19"
"Tanaka 19"
"Sato 51"
"Suzuki 121"
```

Comment: What's your question? Strings will be quoted; that's what makes it a String.

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `p`. [Check this answer out](/a/1255362/5958455)

Comment: Whenever you give an example please show the desired result (as a Ruby object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can get rid of the quotation marks by replacing `p` ([Ruby's inspect/print](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758306/2166798)) with `puts`.

While we're at it, you can make this much more "Ruby-ish" by using `.readlines` to scoop up all the input into an array, and by replacing the multiple counting loops with `.map` or `.each` iterators.  The following is more concise, and allows you to lose the first input line which you're just throwing away anyway.

```
lines = STDIN.readlines(chomp: true).map do |line|
    l = line.split(' ')
    [l[0], l[1].to_i + 1].join(' ')
    # or
    # "#{l[0]} #{l[1].to_i + 1}"
end

lines.each { |line| puts line }
```

With Ruby 3, you can use rightward-assignment for the first part if you find it more readable:

```
STDIN.readlines(chomp: true).map do |line|
    l = line.split(' ')
    "#{l[0]} #{l[1].to_i + 1}"
end => lines
```